# Dynamic CDATA in JAXB using MOXy

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, cdata, moxy

I am using [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php). I have an issue where a property of a java class can be CDATA or not dynamically. For example,

```java
class Embed{  
//@XmlValue only  
//OR @XmlValue @CDATA  
private String value; //THIS CAN BE CDATA OR NOT  
}
```

I have tried solving the issue using inheritance where one subclass has the property as just a value and another one as CDATA. The problem i have with this solution is that the generated Xml has xsi:type and xmlns:xsi information which i don't want since i am upgrading legacy code and i need the resulted xml exactly as the legacy one.

The solution i have tried:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)  
@XmlType(name = "itemType", namespace = "", propOrder = {"embed"}  
public class Item{  
 List`<Embed>` embed;  
 //getter and setters  
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)  
@XmlSeeAlso(EmbedDefault.class, EmbedAsCdata.class)  
public abstract class Embed{

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)    
@XmlType( propOrder = {"value"})  
public class EmbedDefault extends Embed{

@XmlValue
protected String value;
 //getters and setters  
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)  
@XmlType(propOrder = {"value"})  
public class EmbedAsCdata extends Embed {  

@XmlValue
@XmlCDATA
protected String value;
//getters and setters  
}
```

Is there such another easier approach?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

I'm trying to come up with a decent workaround for you, but below is an enhancement request you can follow where we are going to enhance the `@XmlCDATA` annotation to make this use case much easier to support.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/374977

---

**UPDATE #1**

Below is an approach I'm working on for your use case.  It requires a small change to MOXy which I have figured out but still need to fully test.  You can track our progress on this issue using the following link:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/397517

**DomHandler (CdataHandler)**

JAXB has the concept of a `DomHandler` that allows you some extra control of what the XML looks like.  We will leverage a `DomHandler` to add in a `CDATA` block when required.

```java
package forum14145131;

import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.DomHandler;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;

import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class CdataHandler implements DomHandler<String, DOMResult> {

    private static DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();;

    @Override
    public DOMResult createUnmarshaller(ValidationEventHandler veh) {
        return new DOMResult();
    }

    @Override
    public String getElement(DOMResult domResult) {
        Document document = (Document) domResult.getNode();
        return document.getDocumentElement().getTextContent();
    }

    @Override
    public Source marshal(String string, ValidationEventHandler veh) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = db.newDocument();

            Node node;
            if(string.contains("<") || string.contains("&") || string.contains("&")) {
                node = document.createCDATASection(string);
            } else {
                node = document.createTextNode(string);
            }
            return new DOMSource(node);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

**Embed**

The `@XmlAnyElement` annotation is used to specify the `DomHandler`.

```java
package forum14145131;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Embed{  

    @XmlAnyElement(CdataHandler.class)
    private String value; //THIS CAN BE CDATA OR NOT  

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html

---

**UPDATE #2**

Below is an approach that you can use today using the existing EclipseLink library leveraging an `XmlAdapter` and a `CharacterEscapeHandler`:

**XmlAdapter (CdataAdapter)**

```java
package forum14145131;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class CdataAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(String string) throws Exception {
        if(string.contains("&") || string.contains("<") || string.contains("\"")) {
            return "<![CDATA[" + string + "]]>";
        } else {
            return string;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
        return string;
    }

}
```

**Embed**

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation is used to specify the `XmlAdapter`.

```java
package forum14145131;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Embed{  

    @XmlValue
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CdataAdapter.class)
    private String value; //THIS CAN BE CDATA OR NOT  

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

Below is how you specify the `CharacterEscapeHandler`.  Note this overrides all the character escaping for this `Marshaller`.  We do this so the `CDATA` portion doesn't get escaped.  For production code your implementation of this method would need to be beefed up over what is presented in this example.

```java
package forum14145131;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.CharacterEscapeHandler;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Embed.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum14145131/input.xml");
        Embed embed = (Embed) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.CHARACTER_ESCAPE_HANDLER,
                new CharacterEscapeHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void escape(char[] ac, int i, int j, boolean flag,
                            Writer writer) throws IOException {
                        writer.write(ac, i, j);
                    }
                });
        marshaller.marshal(embed, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<embed><![CDATA[Hello & World]]></embed>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. May be you already thought about it but, considering the above issue, the enhancement solution suggested remains to have the same issue. Even if we set the @XmlCDATA(XmlCDATAType.Optional), the question, which is how to identify dynamically if the value is CDATA or not, remains. Or you have something in mind on how to make the decision whether to render CDATA or not when @XmlCDATA(XmlCDATAType.Optional) is used. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1946448 - No problem.  I have updated my answer with another approach, but its going to require a small change to MOXy that I still need to fully test.  For determining the presence of the CDATA block I was just going to check for the presence of `<`, `&`, or `"`, is that sufficient for your use case?

Comment: i sincerely thank you for the update. For update #2, CharacterEscapeHandler will not escape all characters. May be that is why you said it needs "to be beefed up". Do you think this, which is not escaping all characters, could be an issue? If so, can we use some default escaping pattern and modify it to exclude the cdata